# How to add css properties inside the PHP tag

Tags: php, html, css

I need one help.i need to restrict some css display property with PHP condition.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;display:none;" id="compid">Select Company :


</div>
```

Here initially my div's css property `display:none` is there.But i need to `block` this using some php condition like below.

```
<?php if($getcustomerobj->companypro == 1 and $_REQUEST['edit']!=""){display:block}else{display:none}   ?>
```

I need to put the above condition inside the style properties.Please help me how to do it proper way.

Comment: Just use echo to print your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can instanciate your display value before outputing :

```
<?php
$display = ($getcustomerobj->companypro == 1 && $_REQUEST['edit']!="") ? 'block' : 'none';
?>

<div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;display:<?= $display ?>;" id="compid">Select Company :
</div>
```

If you want to mix php and html, you can use php tags inside html :

```
<p><?php echo $something ?></p>
```

or short tags if enabled on your server

```
<p><?= $something ?></p>
```

Comment: No,Its not working.its always display the div no matter is the php condition.

Comment: what do you see in your source code ? If it's always display:block, it's that your $getcustomerobj->companypro is equal to 1 et your $_REQUEST['edit'] is not empty. var_dump these to be sure !

Comment: @subhra Then your PHP conditions are wrong or you have CSS somewhere else overriding the style aggressively.

Comment: I was posting the exact same answer :p 1+.  For future reference , the [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) operator was used instead of `if/else`

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
<div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;<?php if($getcustomerobj->companypro == 1 && $_REQUEST['edit']!=""){echo 'display:block;';}else{echo 'display:none;';}?>" id="compid">Select Company :</div>
```

add your **php** and **echo** in the **style** attribute

Hope it helps !

Comment: there's a site called 3v4l.org where you can check your php before you post answers that don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a variable to the string you want to use as the CSS property.

Just for brevity, I tend to use ternaries for this sort of thing:

```
<?php $display = ($getcustomerobj->companypro == 1 and $_REQUEST['edit']!="") ? 'display:block;' : 'display:none;'; ?>

<div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;<?php echo $display;?>" id="compid">Select Company :

</div>
```

Its not the tidiest solution, you would be better of using HTML classes and separating your CSS, but this should get the job done.

Comment: you hav ean extra quote here: `'display:'none;'`

Comment: In your code this `$display = ($getcustomerobj->companypro == 1 and $_REQUEST['edit']!="") : 'display:block;' : 'display:none;'; ` throwing the syntax error.

Comment: Oh the first colon `:` should be question mark `?`. My typo.